# Can't bind variables in Oracle procedure

Tags: php, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Here's a procedure that I'm trying to run.  It inserts into two tables - `table1` and an association table `table2`.

```
create or replace procedure Insert_Row (summary IN VARCHAR2
   description IN VARCHAR2, status IN NUMBER, 
   date_submitted IN DATE, last_updated IN DATE,
   owner_id IN NUMBER, reporter_id IN NUMBER,
   foo IN VARCHAR2, bar IN VARCHAR2,
   first_assignee IN NUMBER) 
is
   l_cur_id number;
begin
   insert into table1 
      (summary, description, status, date_submitted, 
       last_updated, owner_id, reporter_id, 
       foo, bar)
    values( :summary, :description, :status, 
            to_date(:date_submitted,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
            to_date(:last_updated,'YYYY-MM-DD'), :owner_id, 
            :reporter_id, :foo, :bar)
            returning action_id into l_cur_id; 
    insert into table2(action_id, assignee_id) 
    values(l_cur_id,:test);
    commit;
 end;"
```

Without the parameters, the query works fine.  I.e. if I remove all the `:somethings` and hardcode the values then it runs with no errors when I run `exec Insert_Row;`

With the parameters (with the `:somethings`), there are errors:

`show errors procedure Insert_Row;`

```
Errors: check compiler log
2/4            PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DESCRIPTION" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ) , @ % default character
The symbol "," was substituted for "DESCRIPTION" to continue.

14/13          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'SUMMARY'
14/23          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'DESCRIPTION'
14/37          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'STATUS'
15/21          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'DATE_SUBMITTED'
16/21          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'LAST_UPDATED'
16/50          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OWNER_ID'
17/13          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'REPORTER_ID'
17/27          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'FOO'
17/33          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'BAR'
20/21          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'TEST'
```

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Query after @ron tornambe's solution is:

```
create or replace procedure Insert_Row (summary IN VARCHAR2,
   description IN VARCHAR2, status IN NUMBER, 
   date_submitted IN DATE, last_updated IN DATE,
   owner_id IN NUMBER, reporter_id IN NUMBER,
   foo IN VARCHAR2, bar IN VARCHAR2,
   first_assignee IN NUMBER) 
is
   l_cur_id number;
begin
   insert into table1 
      (summary, description, status, date_submitted, 
       last_updated, owner_id, reporter_id, 
       foo, bar)
    values( :summary, :description, :status, 
            to_date(:date_submitted,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
            to_date(:last_updated,'YYYY-MM-DD'), :owner_id, 
            :reporter_id, :foo, :bar)
            returning action_id into l_cur_id; 
    insert into table2(action_id, assignee_id) 
    values(l_cur_id,:test);
    commit;
 end;"
```

Error after this modification is:

```
14/13          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'SUMMARY'
14/23          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'DESCRIPTION'
14/37          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'STATUS'
15/21          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'DATE_SUBMITTED'
16/21          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'LAST_UPDATED'
16/50          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OWNER_ID'
17/13          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'REPORTER_ID'
17/27          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'FOO'
17/33          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'BAR'
20/21          PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'TEST'
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Remove colon in front of all parameters. so `:somethings` becomes `somethings`.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov Thanks again.  Errors are gone but how do you call the procedure?  I'm doing this in PHP at the moment: `$parse = oci_parse( $conn, $sql ); oci_bind_by_name( $parse, 'summary', $this->summary );` which gives: `Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number` (where `$sql` is the corrected query).

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html) or at [this example](http://anexusit.com:8080/blog/how-execute-oracle-stored-procedures-php-using-oci-functions)

Comment: Okay, I am SO nearly there.  Here's my procedure call: `exec Insert_Action('test','test',1,to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1,1,'test','test','test');` and here's the (hopefully) final error: `Error starting at line 1 in command:
exec Insert_Action('test','test',1,to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1,1,'test','test','test')
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:`

Comment: @ale Your last parameter is a number and you are trying to insert a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
create or replace procedure Insert_Row (summary IN VARCHAR2,
   description IN VARCHAR2, status IN NUMBER, 
   date_submitted IN DATE, last_updated IN DATE,
   owner_id IN NUMBER, reporter_id IN NUMBER,
   foo IN VARCHAR2, bar IN VARCHAR2,
   first_assignee IN NUMBER) 
is
   l_cur_id number;
begin
   insert into table1 
      (summary, description, status, date_submitted, 
       last_updated, owner_id, reporter_id, 
       foo, bar)
    values( summary, description, status, 
            to_date(date_submitted,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
            to_date(last_updated,'YYYY-MM-DD'), owner_id, 
            reporter_id, foo, bar)
            returning action_id into l_cur_id; 
    insert into table2(action_id, assignee_id) 
    values(l_cur_id,test);
    commit;
 end;
```

You do not need to have colon if you are passing parameters, you could directly assign parameter names. Another point is if you are calling this procedure from a client or from front end, better remove commit from your procedure and use commit from your calling client.

Comment: Polppan Please see comment on @Nicholas Krasnov's question comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @ale Do not know much about php, but have a look at [this](http://studiawan.blogspot.com/2007/06/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-in-php.html) and [this as well](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a comma after "summary IN VARCHAR2". Also, the keyword "IN" is the default.7

Comment: @ale Post your modified procedure